# Looping through driver.get() giving ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused error

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to read a list of URLs from .csv file and scrape product price. Any suggestions to loop through urls would be great. I can return price and title of first product and then I get a connection refused error.

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused error

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time

s=Service(executable_path="/Users/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)
source = 'offsaks.csv'
with open(source, 'rt', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(readCSV)
    



    data_list = []
    urls = []

    for row in readCSV:
        url = row[1]
        urls.append(url)


    for url in urls:
        with webdriver as driver:
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            time.sleep(10)
       
            driver.get(url)
            print(url)

    
            xpath = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/span/span[1]/span[2]/span/span').text
            print(xpath)
            title = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/h1/span[2]/span/span').text
            print(title)
     
            data = {
            'Price': xpath,
            'Title': title
            }

            data.update()
            data_list.append(data)
            driver.refresh()
            time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()


df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
df.to_csv('test_1.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Connection refused to what? to your web driver or to the server you're scraping the data from?

Comment: I am not sure... here is the last part of the error message:

raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=53276): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/8f25ca3a6b4cb39e0236eeab44504e0b/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f85c9f15a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

Comment: This error saying that the connection to your WebDriver service is refused which might mean it has been prematurely killed. Give LeoBertass solution a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because of the driver.quit(), you're using it before the for is complete. Try moving it to another path within the code when finished. I also recommend using try and catch in your python application in selenium, I believe it will be easier to find errors.

Try like this:

```
try:
        xxxxxxxxxx
        for url in urls:
         xxxxxxx
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```